# i'am trying to remove a user from a local group throught AD (powershell)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

i'm trying to develop a script that remove a domain user from local administrators group  (i can use computer management from ad but its a graphical interface i need to do it with commands) for now i'm using invoke command to remotely connect to machines and remove their users from local admins group .

im using this command : `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $line2.split(";")[0]  -ScriptBlock {  net localgroup "administrators" $using:notadmin  /DELETE  } -Credential $Cred`

the problem here if a the machine is not online i need to wait until it will be online , i'm searching how to remove users from local group (administrators for example ) through ad

is there a command to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried [Remove-LocalGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/remove-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: in my case this command need to be used from the client it self , i need to execute my script from AD (to remove a domain user from administrators group on that host)

Comment: Surely any command to do this will need to be run locally as that's where the local group is defined, and if it's offline, then, no matter the method, you'll always need to wait until it is online again to do anything.  If you mean that you want it to happen automatically when the machine comes online, then the Restricted Groups option below of a Startup Script would look like your only options.

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches: 
If you would like to use Group Policy, you may check for: Restricted groups.

https://www.petri.com/manage-local-active-directory-groups-using-group-policy-restricted-groups

Another option would be to incoroporate `Test-Connection` in your script, validating if computer is online. If it is - execute the script, if it is not, store it in another list with offline machines. 
Then later run the script against the offline machine list ... and so on until all the computers are being covered.

P.S. And yes, as suggested in the commments, consider using remove-localgroupmember, if your powershell version support it.

Again, depends of the case. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: in my case i need to develop a powershell script to remove a domain user from local administarors group on a machine x the script will have privileges to be executed from the AD server (my problem is i cant find the commands that remove the domain account from machine x administrators group remotrly , PS : i can do it graphically) , in Remov-localgroupmember case ill need to execute the cmdlet from machine x so it not what i need

Comment: Again, you may use Invoke-command to execute on the remonte computer. As stated in the post, you may filter the offline computers. When running this multiple times again the offline list computers, the list will get shorter and shorter, until all computers are being covered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$RemoteComputer = "yourComputer"

$Computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://$RemoteComputer,computer")
$Group = $Computer.PSBase.Children.Find("Administrators")

ForEach ($User in (Get-Content 
"c:\users\administrator.domain\desktop\localadmin.txt"))
{   $Group.Remove("WinNT://$User")
}
```

i tired this code and it really helped me thnx for help